# Compress a directory using tar/gz over SSH to local computer?

Tags: bash, ssh, tar

I'd like to essentially tar/gz a directory on a remote machine and save the file to my local computer without having to connect back into my local machine from the remote one. Is there a way to do this over SSH? The tar file doesn't need to be stored on the remote machine, only on the local machine. Is this possible?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can do it with an ssh command, just tell `tar` to create the archive on its standard output:

```
ssh remote.example.com 'cd /path/to/directory && tar -cf - foo | gzip -9' >foo.tgz
```

Another approach, which is more convenient if you want to do a lot of file manipulations on the other machine but is overkill for a one-shot archive creation, is to mount the remote machine's filesystem with [SSHFS](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) (a [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) filesystem). You should enable compression at the SSH level.

```
mkdir ~/net/remote.example.com
sshfs -C remote.example.com:/ ~/net/remote.example.com
tar -czf foo.tgz -C ~/net/remote.example.com/path/to/directory foo
```

Comment: I'm just curious, why'd you recommend `tar -cf - foo | gzip -9` instead of `tar -czf - foo` or `tar -cz foo`?

Comment: @Patrick Slightly more portable, e.g. it'll work on Solaris.

Comment: Would you be so kind to describe all arguments?

Comment: @RooticalV. `tar -cf - foo` creates (`-c`) archive on the standard output (`-f -`) from file `foo`. `gzip -9` uses the best (slowest) compression method. If you don't care, you can just use `ssh remote.example.com tar cz /path/to/directory/foo > foo.tar.gz`.

Comment: @mhellmeier The command you posted does exclude `foo/bar` and the files beneath it, at least with GNU tar.

Answer (score 1):

**Use this command to copy to a remote destination:**

```
tar -c --zstd <src files> | ssh user@target_host "cd target_dir && tar -x --zstd"
```

**Tar flags:**

-c: create new tar'd output (defaults to stdout)

--zstd: use zstd compression ([faster than gzip, the algorithm for tar](http://facebook.github.io/zstd/#benchmarks))

-x: extract output (defaults to stdin)

**Measure line rate for benchmarking:**

```
tar -c --zstd <src files> | pv --timer --rate | ssh user@target_host "cd target_dir && tar -x --zstd"
```

**Compression benchmark**

Environment: local wifi between laptop and desktop (limited to ~40MiB/s)

Gzip: 0:04:59

Zstd: 0:03:04

Answer (score -1):

For a simple way to copy a directory or file by compressing it only for the transport:

```
$ ssh domain.net 'ls foo'
file1   file2

$ ssh domain.net 'tar czf - foo' | tar xz

$ ls foo
file1   file2
```

Comment: This does not store the `tar` archive on the local machine, which was what was intended.

Comment: This is for people landing on this question (like me) when searching how to copy something through SSH with compression. There is just this additional `tar xz` out of the pipe with a simpler and more readable example.