# Tar and download in one step over ssh / scp

Tags: ssh, tar, scp, download

*(This seems like an obvious / common question, but I couldn't find it when searching - maybe I wasn't using the correct terminology...)*

I want to login over ssh to a remote machine, tar a directory, and download it to my local machine. I don't need to leave a copy on the remote server. Currently I ssh in, create the tar archive, logout, scp the file to my machine, the ssh back in to remove the archive. Not exactly efficient...

I know this doesn't work, but I'm thinking something like:

```
scp user@remote:"tar czf - /my/directory/" ./my/local/destination/archive.tgz
```

Or is there a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: Using only one step is complex

Comment: @Marco yes looks like a matching dup

Comment: @Marco - thanks, I knew it must have been asked and I just wasn't searching with the right terms...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you follow your description the command becomes "obvious" (at least, when you see it...). You really weren't far off with your attempt, though:

```
ssh user@remote tar czf - /my/directory/ > /my/local/destination/archive.tgz
```

(The "[duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19804/compress-a-directory-using-tar-gz-over-ssh-to-local-computer)" link cited by Marco provides a cleaner solution. To create this command here I've simply followed the style of your attempt.)

Comment: i'd go with the pipeline solution in the dup link except i would seriously consider having the remote host do the compression to reduce network bandwidth load.

Comment: Your answer was great  @roaima

Comment: @Skaperen this version also does compression on the remote host (the `z` flag)

Comment: You don't need `f -`, standard output is used by default. I like this solution better than the other answer, because this way you can use tab completion.

Comment: @arekolek that depends on your `tar`. Some versions default to a tape device.